# How to forward local-user's groups to the container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My docker command is pretty rich, but still I am not able to see all the local-user's groups when I am inside container. Question is how can I do that?

So from outside docker:

```
$>>groups
<$USER> adm cdrom sudo dip video plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

My docker-run command:

```
docker run -it \
--restart=on-failure:5 \
--name amr_sdk_docker \
--user "$(id --user):$(id --group)" \
--group-add "$(id --group)" \
--hostname "$(hostname)" \
--env "USER=$(whoami)" \
--env "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" \
--env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
--network=host \
--security-opt apparmor:unconfined \
--security-opt=no-new-privileges \
--pids-limit 128 \
--volume /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
--volume "${HOME}":/home/"$(whoami)":rw \
--volume "${HOME}"/.cache:/.cache:rw \
--volume /run/user:/run/user \
--volume /var/run/nscd/socket:/var/run/nscd/socket:ro \
--volume /etc/ssl/certs/:/etc/ssl/certs/:ro \
--volume /etc/ssh/:/etc/ssh/:ro \
--volume /usr/share/ca-certificates:/usr/share/ca-certificates:ro \
--volume /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro \
--volume /etc/group:/etc/group:ro \
--volume /usr/local/share/ca-certificates:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates:ro \
--volume /dev:/dev \
--volume /lib/modules:/lib/modules \
--volume /tmp:/tmp:rw \
--privileged \
<image_name:tag>
```

And after above command, from inside container:

```
$ groups
<$USER>
```

Comment: If the Docker container is privileged, has access to the entire host filesystem, uses host networking, needs the containing process's environment, and has the host user ID and host group IDs, what benefit are you getting from running the process in Docker?  It doesn't seem like the process will be isolated from the host system at all, and it might be much easier to just run it directly.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for replying. Docker run command is not my concern. User can cut short it as needed. My concern is getting user access to groups which are visible outside but not inside docker.

Comment: I have proposed a solution to this problem using vscode's devcontainers: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7722 if the issue can get enough up votes then maybe it will be implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem exactly, however you are currently passing only the effective group ID with `--group-add`. This is already taken care of by:

```
--user "$(id --user):$(id --group)"
```

What you might be missing is adding a `--group-add` argument for each of your local group IDs, which can be identified for your user on the host with:

```
id --groups
```